# Image Processing in C# - A smart solution?

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have an image with letters in it, the letters are in two colors black and blue, I want to read the blue colored letters from the image.

Can anyone suggest me a method to do this in C#. Iam studying GDI+,but still didn't get any logic to develop this program..

I tried OCRing it, but the issue with common OCRs is that they dont recognize the color difference.

I only want to read the Blue characters....

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: How does your OCR technique work? Can it only detect black characters on a white background? Or is there some other problem?

Comment: for OCR Iam using Terrasact and open source OCR from google, its working fine with most of the images but for some images its displaying latin or greek characters, some terrsact experienced person might help in this segment..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one ;) But that's unsafe code.

```
void RedAndBlue()
{

    OpenFileDialog ofd;
    int imageHeight, imageWidth;

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Image tmp = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        imageHeight = tmp.Height;
        imageWidth = tmp.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }

    int[,] bluePixelArray = new int[imageWidth, imageHeight];
    int[,] redPixelArray = new int[imageWidth, imageHeight];
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tmp.Width, tmp.Height);
    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(tmp);
    BitmapData bmpData = temp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int remain = bmpData.Stride - bmpData.Width * 3;
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        for (int j = 0; j < bmpData.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bmpData.Width; i++)
            {
                bluePixelArray[i, j] = ptr[0];
                redPixelArray[i, j] = ptr[2];
                ptr += 3;
            }
            ptr += remain;
        }
    }
    temp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    temp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to do bitmap pixel manipulation. The "unsafe" keyword is unfortunate in this case, since it's only really unsafe if you aren't good at math. "notaspathethicallyslowasgetpixelandsetpixel" would be a more appropriate keyword for this.

Comment: I have to warn him about 'unsafe' part because he needs to allow unsafe code before. And you are right about "notaspathethicallyslowasgetpixelandsetpixel" :)

Comment: +1 for this, but should you also call temp.Dispose() after the final UnlockBits operation?

Comment: @Andy i've copied this code from my own project and it already has dispose(); 

Now i'm adding it here too :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet, this code works like charm for me...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Modify the color of the image to gray scaled then use OCR

```
public Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
    {
        //make an empty bitmap the same size as original
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
            {
                //get the pixel from the original image
                Color originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);

                //create the grayscale version of the pixel
                int grayScale = (int)((originalColor.R * .3) + (originalColor.G * .59)
                    + (originalColor.B * .11));

                //create the color object
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);

                //set the new image's pixel to the grayscale version
                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }

        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably modify the palette to have only black and white on the image